# loading PHP file to another PHP file with AJAX with viewable source code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am working on a simple CRUD application in PHP with AJAX. Reading and adding records works well. However, when it comes to updating and deleting, it doesn't function.

read_categories.php

```
<?php
include_once '../../config/Database.php';

echo "<table class='table'>
<tr>
    <th>Category Name</th>
    <th></th>
</tr>";

$result = DB::query("SELECT c.* FROM categories c;");
foreach ($result as $row) {
    echo "<tr>
        <td style='padding-top:15px;'>" . $row['CategoryName'] . "</td>
        <td>
            <button class='btn btn-warning btn-sm'>Edit</button> 
            <button onclick='deleteCategory(" . $row['CategoryID'] .");' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm'>Delete</button>
        </td>
    </tr>";
} //for loading categories table
echo "</table>";
?>
```

category.js

```
function showCategories(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "category-scripts/read_categories.php"
    }).done(function(data){
        $('#category-list').html(data);
    });
}
```

The list of records that are fetched from the DB will be loaded in:

```
<div id="category-list"></div>
```

in `categories.php`

However, I can't find the source code, which means even if I write another JS function for the edit and delete buttons, it won't run. Is there any way to load tags in PHP file with AJAX with viewable source?

Comment: you can't find what source code? please edit your question until it makes sense.

Comment: I'm sorry, that was due to internet connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create similar js function for editing and deleting Categories

Use id parameter to pass the id of the editing / deleting category so that you know which category is to be edited / deleted.

```js
$('.editBtn').click(function(){ 

var testId = $(this).attr('id'); // testId will have edit_1 , edit_2 depending upon catID
    
var temp = testId .split('_');
var selectedId = temp[1]; 

//So, temp[1] will have the numeric ID value.

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST,
        data: { 'id' : selectedId },
        url: "category-scripts/categories.php"
    }).done(function(data){
        $('#category-list').html(data); // OR here you can call the 
                                       //showCategories() function
    });

});
```

Note: you can get this 'selectedID' by assigning category ID to edit button / delete button.

Hint here would be that

```
<button class='btn btn-warning btn-sm editBtn' id='edit_'<?php echo $row['CategoryID'];?>>Edit</button>
```

Now you have categoryID in category.php so you can write edit or delete query based on this categoryID

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try.

Comment: Sure, and post further if you run into any issue.